# i am looking to apply media queries through javascript

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I want to slide the divs of menu from left to right,I have done that using javascript

```
     <div id="script" style="height: 250px;">
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="div1" class="slide-item">
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="div2" class="slide-item">
                        <p>About Us</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="div3" class="slide-item">
                        <p>Events</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="div4" class="slide-item">
                        <p>Register</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

But I cant do it with different media screen I have tried this:

```
   document.ready(function () {

if (screen.width <= 450) {
    $("#div1").animate({ left: '100px' }, { duration: 500 });

}
else if (screen.width >= 451 && screen.width <= 700) {
    $("#div1").animate({ left: '150px' }, { duration: 500 });
}
else (screen.width > 700)
{
    $("#div1").animate({ left: '200px' }, { duration: 500 });
}
```

I have also tried using switch case:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
    switch ( varmql) {
        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 450px)"):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '60px' }, { duration: 500 });

            break;
        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width:540px)"):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '80px' }, { duration: 500 });

            break;

        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 541px) and (max-width:768px)"):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '100px' }, { duration: 500 });

            break;

        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width:1024px)"):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '140px' }, { duration: 500 });

            break;
        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width:1200px)"):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '160px' }, { duration: 500 });

            break;
        case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1201px) "):
            $("#div1").animate({ left: '180px' }, { duration: 500 });
        default

    }


});
```

doing this the slide item is not appearing at all on screen

Comment: Maybe you can animate them trhrough CSS, animate them for the whole width of their container, and set that container width based on media queries in the CSS.

Comment: Are you listening for the `resize` event in the first method you tried, or the `matchMedia` change event for the second method?

Comment: I have done this work in js fiddle, its working completely fine I am confused where to add media query for mobiles and tablets etc

Comment: what I am trying is it should not go upto 250px from left as the size decrease it should stop at say 100px for mobiles ,130px for tablets etc

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwknqev8/1/

Comment: `matches` is a boolean flag that you can receive out of `matchMedia`. That can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `matchMedia` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia.

It returns a "media query list" on which you have to access the `matches` property:

```
case window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 450px)").matches:
                                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

I don't know what `varmql` is, but it would seem you should replace it with `true`.

But as a commenter mentioned, you probably don't need to this at all. You can use CSS with media queries:

```
#div1 { transition: all 500ms; }

@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
    #div1 .animate { left: 60px; }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').addClass('animate');
});
```

or something similar.